# How can I select from a query written in another script, SQL Plus?

Tags: oracle, scripting, subquery, sqlplus

Let's say I have a query:

SELECT * FROM TABLE

and I want to be able to save this in a script locally so I can query from it, much like a view.  (My reason is that I do not have permissions to create views in the database I'm working with.)

Let's say I want to save the above query as "basic.sql".

I want to be able to write another query like for example:

Select query1."column1" from basic.sql query1

Or something to this effect.  I have tried:

Select query1.column1 from @"path/to/basic.sql" query1

But this does not yield the results.